# when protractor running in docker and chrome browser is in headless mode then getting "element not visible"

Tags: docker, protractor, headless-browser

In UI, we have one pop-up window which opens after import completed.

Use-case: I wants to click on the link of pop-up window after import and then verify elements of pop-up window.

When I am running locally in IDE, all testcases of protractor are passing. But when i am running inside docker, it fails with "element not visible".

I have added `browser.actions().mouseMove(eleViewDetailBar).perform();` to navigate to that element but No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to the xvfb [default window size](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/a6d2fe6ec8/NodeBase/Dockerfile#L32) (1360x1020) we choose by the time it was setup. You can use this [alternative docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium#screen-size) project I maintain and setup the resolution at docker run time via `-e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480`:

```
docker pull elgalu/selenium:2.47.1n

docker run --rm --name=grid -p 4444:24444 -p 5920:25900 \
  -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola \
  -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480 \
  elgalu/selenium:2.47.1n

docker exec grid wait_all_done 10s

open vnc://:hola@localhost:5920
```

Also try to set the browser window initial position to (0,0) but that depends on the selenium framework you're using.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the docker-selenium official maintainers.